# How to invoke the dark theme selection on Google's search page?

Tags: google-search, javascript, userscripts, greasemonkey

This is for Firefox. I know there are extensions for dark themes, but I don't want to use it because it messes up certain websites and doesn't get back to normal even after removing the extension.

**What I want to do:**
Instead, I want to create a script which can be run with GreaseMonkey or an equivalent.
On Google's search page, there's a gear icon for "Quick Settings". On clicking it, these options are shown:
[image]

Instead of having to manually click it, I want a script to auto-detect that I opened a Google page, and automatically click that "Dark theme" radio button.

**What I tried:**
Found the div:

```
<label class="GZcH3e LZTko" jsname="I7WXBf" style="display:flex" data-ved="2ahUKEwiY_7-G9ZCAAxWT-jgGHdrgDFoQ9ZsIegQIIBAN">
<div class="UCGAnb">Dark theme</div>
<img class="UCAEse" src="https://www.gstatic.com/ui/v1/menu/dark_thumbnail2.png" alt="">
</label>
```

Assuming that clicking the radio button invokes a JavaScript function, I searched for `I7WXBf` and found this:

```
class\x3d\x22GZcH3e LZTko\x22 jsname\x3d\x22I7WXBf\x22 style\x3d\x22display:flex\x22 data-ved\x3d\x222ahUKEwiY_7-G9ZCAAxWT-jgGHdrgDFoQ9ZsIegQIIBAN\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22UCGAnb\x22\x3eDark theme\x3c/div\x3e\x3cimg
```

But I find it hard to figure out how it'd get invoked.
I also asked ChatGPT to create a GreaseMonkey script based on the class names from the relevant HTML, but the script didn't work.

Comment: Using ChatGPT for programming/scripting is generally a waste of time. It can be right, but often you have to guide it onto correct path yourself and it's hard to do that if you lack knowledge about a specific topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things for no reason. Just click on the `<div>` element that you mentioned, you don't have to invoke anything. You need to narrow it down with a better selector then, also. E.g. this works for me:

```
document.querySelector('div.de2Dud:nth-child(2)').click();
```

The CSS selector means 2nd child `div` with class `de2Dud`, which is the "random" class name of all the radio `div`s.

**Note, especially for future readers**: the class name could easily be renamed as it seems to be perhaps autogenerated by some JS library. Or perhaps even it may differ per language/country.

Here's one which is class-name independent:

```
document.querySelector('div[role="dialog"] g-radio-button-group:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-child(2)').click();
```

It selects the popup menu, then the 1st `g-radio-button-group` inside and lastly the 2nd `div` which is a direct child.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me: `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null`. I pressed `F12` and entered the command in the `Console`. May I know how you figured out the class is "de2Dud"? I used `Ctrl+u` and searched. I saved the google page to disk and used `grep` to search, but I couldn't find `de2Dud`.

Comment: On which link exactly (paste full one please) did you test?

Comment: Example link: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=hello. I type the search query ("Hello") in the address bar (this is in Firefox, with 'do not remember history' enabled. I also have adblock and uBlock origin installed).

Comment: Works for me under these cirmunstances, except Adblock one, but that shouldn't matter. Maybe it differs per language/country or browser version.

Comment: The class-name independent script worked. The one unanswered question was, how did you figure out the de2Dud? Like I mentioned earlier, I searched a lot for that string but couldn't see it used anywhere. Even if it changes to another string later, I'd need to know how to find the new string. I guess I'll go ahead and create my greasemonkey script now. Thanks!

Comment: I can't describe how I found it because it's just a random `div` with that class. it's simply the whole wrapper of that option, which all of child `div`s of `g-radio-button-group` have for me. If you can't find it normally and the previous selector didn't work then you just don't have it and/or it's other random string, for whatever reason.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. btw, I just found out that Greasemonkey isn't being actively maintained. Using TamperMonkey now.